# Class weights with multiple (sigmoid) binary output

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a simple model run as;

```
from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM, Dropout,
rnn_nodes = 64
num_outs=1

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(rnn_nodes, input_shape=(X.shape[1], X.shape[2]),return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dense(num_outs, use_bias=False, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
history = model.fit(X, y, class_weight=class_weight)
```

Here y is binary in {0, 1}. If num_outs=1, then

```
class_1_bias = y.mean(axis=0)
class_weight = {0 : class_1_bias, 1 : 1.0 - class_1_bias}
```

will give me what I want, and works as expected. But if num_outs > 1, and each output has a different bias I'd like to reflect in training, I can't seem to add this to the model.
num_outs could potentially be large, so training multiple single output node models is not what I want to do.

If anyone has any tips on this, I'd love to know. I'll post any answers if I work it out in the mean time.

Thanks,
Ben.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/2115) looks like a similar issue, it will require a bit of work to adapt to your problem, but it should work